# How to show bar chart in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with multiple bars in Python. The bar chart should display values on top of each bar.
I have a data set like the following:

```
Speciality                  Very interested Somewhat_interested Notinterested
Big Data (Spark/Hadoop)         1332           729                      127
Data Analysis / Statistics      1688           444                      60     
Data Journalism                 429            1081                     610
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd_dataframe = pd.read_csv('Test-Barchart.csv')
no_of_xaxis = pd_dataframe.Speciality.nunique()
ind = np.arange(no_of_xaxis)
xcord = pd_dataframe['Speciality'].tolist()

veryinterestedlist = pd_dataframe['Very interested'].tolist()
somewhatlist = pd_dataframe['Somewhat interested'].tolist()
notinterestedlist = pd_dataframe['Not interested'].tolist()

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
width=0.8

rects1 = ax.bar(ind, veryinterestedlist, width, color='r')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind, somewhatlist, width, color='g')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind+width*2, notinterestedlist, width, color='b')

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0]), ('Very Interested', 
 'Somewhat Interested', 'Not Interested') )

def autolabel(rects):
   for rect in rects:
    h = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%d'%int(h),
            ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)

ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( xcord )
plt.show()
```

The problem is, `plt.show()` is not showing anything!
I don't have any errors in the code. 
Could you please help me resolve this problem?
Also how can i change bar color to hex code color instead of r,g or b? e.g.  #5bc0de

Comment: In fact, runnng your code, I get a graph. A messy graph, but still a graph. Are you sure you posted your actual code? Regarding the question about hex code, just replace `color='g'` with `color='#5bc0de'`.

Comment: yes this is the actual code. I need to have bar chart. on x axis specialty like Big Data, Data Analysis.... and for each Specialty i need to show three bars with different colors. Bar for interested, bar for somewhat interested and last bar for not interested

Comment: Certainly you have errore either in the code or the data since the column headers do not match. Anyway make sure you are using an interactive backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Small changes to your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pd_dataframe = pd.read_csv('Test-Barchart.csv')
no_of_xaxis = pd_dataframe.Speciality.nunique()
ind = np.arange(no_of_xaxis)
width = 0.1
xcord = pd_dataframe['Speciality'].tolist()

veryinterestedlist = pd_dataframe['Very interested'].tolist()
somewhatlist = pd_dataframe['Somewhat interested'].tolist()
notinterestedlist = pd_dataframe['Not interested'].tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = ax.bar(ind, veryinterestedlist, width, color='g')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, somewhatlist, width, color='c')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind+2*width, notinterestedlist, width, color='r')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('y label')
ax.set_title('Title')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(xcord)

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0]), ('Very Interested', 
 'Somewhat Interested', 'Not Interested') )

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)

plt.show()
```

and you get:

[image]

Reference: [Grouped bar chart with labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. How can I assign different color for each bar using hex code color e.g. ##5bc0de

Comment: Just replace `color='c'` with `color='#5bc0de'`, for example: `rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, somewhatlist, width, color='#5bc0de')`

Comment: It's working. Many thanks. I'm sorry for asking many questions but i'm still beginner. The displayed bar chart has a lot of formatting issues like the following image:

Comment: Use `width = 0.1`.

Comment: the requirement is to keep width on 0.8